# How to display the following result in WPF chart

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

In my WPF application, I have a following query to display the selected date range as 'Date' and total number of servers being processed on each day as 'Amount'.

```
  var query_1 = 

  (this.db.Servers
  .Where(a => (a.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && a.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value)
   && ((a.ServerID == "ServerID1" || a.ServerID == "ServerID2") && a.Type == "Complete"))
  .GroupBy(a => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date))
  .OrderBy(a => a.Key)
  .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Amount = g.Count() }))
  .ToList();
```

which returns the output as following when bind to a ListBox's ItemsSource ( just to check whether the query works correctly)

[image: Result]

Now how to bind this result, **Date** and **Amount** to  the WPF chart X and Y axis. ( X- Axis for Date and Y-Axis for Amount).

The chart can be either Bubble Series/Line Series or Column series.

Comment: You need some Chart Control to do that. There are a few commercial ones out there. Personally I don't know any free solution which supports data binding.

Comment: I use WPF toolkit chart control at the moment. my question is how to bind the values in the figure 1 to the chart control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in the msdn forums. for those who want to refer to the solution in the future.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2c4fc325-83c1-4b07-b77a-bc7070c558f3/?prof=required

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This blogpost may have what you need.

http://www.itdevspace.com/2010/09/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-chart-example.html

Basically you to place the information that you retrieve from your LINQ query into a Collection like the list you have (the example in the blog post above uses and ObservableCollection probably for Notification purposes) and then Chart ItemSource property to the Collection, the IndependentValue to the Date, and DependentValue to the Amount.

```
<charting:LineSeries
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}"
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}"
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amount}"/>
```

I haven't tried this on anonymous types so you may to need to change your query logic to be more explicit. The above xaml code expects the DataContext to have a Collection by the name Data containing Items with Properties Date and Amount.